# IE Doesn't run remote JS properly but local runs fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My page works in every browser except in IE 10. When I run this page locally in IE 10 there seems to be no problem whatsoever, only when I open the page remotely with IE 10.

The JavaScript is supposed to measure the div with main text and set the height and width of the div's that are off-screen. This is done wrong by IE 10. The width of these div's has to be set because otherwise the will not animate in properly when an item from the menu is clicked.

I did a check on deprecated functions but found none. 
I checked the syntax and nothing wrong there. (as far as i can see)
The console in IE does not report any errors.

Anyone any idea as for why locally it works fine in every browser, but remotely the only browser that displays it faulty is IE?

EDIT:

I have removed the function brackets at init so the DOM can initiate, although this did not fix the problem.

script (embedded in the head of the page):

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mainTextDiv = null;
var animate;
var acc = 0;
var currentTab = "home";
var nextTab;
var working = 0;
var bar = 600;
var divW;

function init(){


    onWC(currentTab);
    document.getElementById(currentTab).style.width = 'auto';
    divW = document.getElementById(currentTab).offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById("home").style.width = divW + "px";
    document.getElementById("profile").style.width = divW + "px";
    document.getElementById("news").style.width = divW + "px";
    document.getElementById("forums").style.width = divW + "px";
    document.getElementById("webshop").style.width = divW + "px";
    document.getElementById("status").style.width = divW + "px";

}

function onWC(tab){
    var divh = document.getElementById(tab).offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('tabcontainer').style.height = ( divh + 50 ) + "px";
}
function moveDiv(tabName){
    if (currentTab == tabName){
        return;
    }
    if (working == 1){
        return;
    }
    working = 1;
    nextTab = tabName;
    removeDiv();
}
function removeDiv(){
    mainTextDiv = document.getElementById(currentTab);
    mainTextDiv.style.left = parseInt(mainTextDiv.style.left) + (0.5+acc) + "px";
    if (parseInt(mainTextDiv.style.left) > 2000){
        mainTextDiv.style.left = 2000 + "px";
        onWC(nextTab);
        getDiv();
        return;
    }

    acc += 0.15;

    animate = setTimeout(removeDiv,10);
}
function getDiv(){
    mainTextDiv = document.getElementById(nextTab);
    mainTextDiv.style.left = parseInt(mainTextDiv.style.left) - (0.5+acc) + "px";   
    if (parseInt(mainTextDiv.style.left) <= 0){
        mainTextDiv.style.left = 0 + "px";
        currentTab = nextTab;
        working = 0;
        return;
    }

    acc -= 0.15;

    animate = setTimeout(getDiv,15);
}
window.onload = init;
window.onresize = init;

$(function() {
    $("#menu ul li a").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#525252");
            $(this).css("color", "#FFF");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF");
            $(this).css("color", "#525252");
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: What message, if any, do you get in your console? Did you clear your cache?

Comment: is the problem happens only in IE?

Comment: Is the pasted code the .js file?

Comment: @Paul oh wow thanks i did not know i could see that... : cant get offsetHeight from non-defined or empty element

Comment: Is the jQuery loading path correct? Just in case if other browsers load a cached page, and IE loads it from a server.

Comment: @Teemu Just checked that again, yes it is the correct path

Comment: Your web page has a number of validation errors that you might want to check into. Specifically You are missing a `<html>` and I think you have a poorly formatted `DOCTYPE`. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsample.srinformatics.nl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: @Matthew The XHTML errors are all fixed, but the problem still exists

Answer (score 3):

Change `window.onresize = init();` to `window.onresize = init;`

As it stands, the `init()` is trying to run immediately when the JS file is loaded, which is throwing the error because the DOM hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: that did not help, which was expected because the onresize is called when the page is resized which in general only happens when the page has already loaded.

Comment: If you check the console, you should not be seeing that offsetHeight from non-defined or empty element error anymore. You're correct that window.onresize does not run until the page loads, however, when setting window.onresize to init(), you're actually setting it to the return value of init(), meaning the function is running immediately. By eliminating the "()", you're stopping the function from running when the file is first loaded and it should simply only run when the onresize event occurs.

Comment: @Teemu yes i tried it you can see the newly uploaded code on my page

Comment: So what step exactly is it failing on now? What is supposed to happen that isn't? You can replicate the problem in JSFiddle?

Comment: @theJowBiz it does not happen in JSFiddle. I am going to update the explanation.